# Advanced search on multiple associations in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Im trying to build advanced search finder for my Candidate model.
Lets imagine it has couple fields + multiple associations like `has_many: languages` & `has_many: skills`. Now I'm building query like this:

```
query = Candidate.select("*")
if position_name
  query = query.where('position_name LIKE ? OR position_name IS NULL',"%#{position_name}%")
end 

if salary
  query = query.where('salary <= ? OR salary IS NULL',salary)
end
```

and so on...

Now I want to add more advanced conditions like to find users who only have such skills like `PHP` and `Java` (so return only those users who have both skills)

This works but only when I insert `OR`

```
  query = query.joins(:skills)
  query = query.where('`skills`.`name` = ? OR `skills`.`name` = ?',"Java","PHP")
```

Additionally I'd like the same also for languages (plus, language have `language.name` & `language.level`)

Can someone points me in which direction to look? And also how to build such  condition where I can multiple skills or multiple languages?

Comment: You may seriously want to consider using a search engine like [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) since it makes tasks like this one trivial and also makes the search blazing fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the various search gems like Ransack, Metawhere or Searchlogic

http://rubygems.org/gems/ransack

https://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic

Both Ransack and Searchlogic allow searching on associated models and you can use scopes to restrict the search parameters.

Example Search params for Searchlogic.

```
[search][admitted_gte]  

[search][admitted_lte]  

[search][aetiology_like_any][]  VIRUS

[search][at_risk_gte]   

[search][at_risk_lte]   

[search][died_gte]  

[search][died_lte]  

[search][gezi_reference_like]   

[search][id]    

[search][incidents_location_encrypted_postcode_like]    

[search][lab_confirmed_gte] 

[search][lab_confirmed_lte] 

[search][onset_first_after] 

[search][onset_first_before]    

[search][onset_last_after]  

[search][onset_last_before] 

[search][outbreak_type_equals_any][]    FOODBORNE

[search][point_source_date_after]   

[search][point_source_date_before]  

[search][total_affected_gte]    

[search][total_affected_lte]    

[search][user_reference_like]   

[search][year_equals_any][] 2010

search[order]   descend_by_id
```

Outbreak_Controller.rb Index action returns the results of the Search query. From 17 Search params only a single searchlogic call is required @`search = Outbreak.search(params[:search])`. The params are whitelisted against a list of allowed search params - code not shown.

```
def index

          #set the default index order to be descending Outbreak id
          if !params[:search][:order]
              params[:search][:order] = "descend_by_id"  
          end
          if params[:search][:bacterial_agents_bacterium_name_like_any] != nil && !params[:search][:bacterial_agents_bacterium_name_like_any].empty?
              params[:search][:bacterial_agents_category_like] = "CAUSATIVE"
          end
          if params[:search][:viral_agents_virus_name_like_any] != nil && !params[:search][:viral_agents_virus_name_like_any].empty?
              params[:search][:viral_agents_category_like] = "CAUSATIVE"
          end
          if params[:search][:protozoal_agents_protozoa_name_like_any] != nil && !params[:search][:protozoal_agents_protozoa_name_like_any].empty?
              params[:search][:protozoal_agents_category_like] = "CAUSATIVE"
          end
          if params[:search][:toxic_agents_toxin_name_like_any] != nil && !params[:search][:toxic_agents_toxin_name_like_any].empty?
              params[:search][:toxic_agents_category_like] = "CAUSATIVE"
          end
  #Outbreak.search takes all of the given params and runs it against the Outbreak model and it's associated models
  @search = Outbreak.search(params[:search])
end
```